# node: res.locals is undefined?

Tags: node.js, api, jwt

I am trying to make an authetication middle to check if token received is valid and pass on the user data with res.locals, but when I try to access res.local the given err comes up.

authmiddleware : to check if the token is valid and if user exist then pass on.

```
exports.authMiddleware = function (req, res, next) {
    const token = req.headers.authorization;

    if (token) {
        const user = parseToken(token);

        User.findById(user.userId, function (err, u) {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(422).send({
                    errors: normalizeErrors(err.errors)
                });
            }
            if (u !== null) {
                res.locals.user = u;
                console.log(res.locals)
                console.log(u)
                next();
            } else {
                return notAuthorized(res);
            }
        })
    } else {
        return notAuthorized(res);
    }
}
```

**controller to exatract user from re.locals, but the err comes out as can't read user of undifined.**

```
exports.changeAddress = function(req,res) {
    const {user} = req.locals;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because there is no field called `locals` on `req` object.
I assume `changeAddress` is a POST route and `locals` is sent from the client as a POST request body in JSON form.

If that is the case you should access `locals` like this,
`req.body.locals`

Bear in mind that since the request body is JSON you will need express to parse it properly.

For this, you need to install the `body-parser` middleware dependency,

`npm i body-parser`

And then add this middleware to your express app,

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
app.use(bodyParser.json())
```

Reference: https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/body-parser.html